# How to improve filter-as-you-type responsiveness in Meteor / Minimongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm pretty new to Meteor. I have an app with a reasonably small data set, < 1000 records, and I build a fairly naive filter-as-you-type implementation.

Right now, the performance is pretty awful - every keypress causes the browser to comply freeze for a second or two on a relatively fast computer.

It currently has `autopublish` enabled and is doing everything on the client which I know is a big part of the problem, I'm just not sure how to improve it.

This is the relevant code snippet:

```
  Template.results.codes = function () {
    var query = Session.get("query")
    // todo: figure out if there's a better way to do this
    var search = (query && query.length > 3) ? {$where: function() {
        return this.code.indexOf(query) != -1;
    }} : {}
    return Codes.find(search);
  };
```

You can see the full source at https://github.com/nfriedly/Meteor-ODB-II and try it out at http://odb-ii.meteor.com/

Specific questions I have:

- Is there a better way to search mongo db / minimongo?
- Is there a straight forward way of moving the search out of the UI thread? Either with web-workers or else by just running it on the server?
- Is there a way for my template to know the difference between "the data is still loading", and "there's no data in this collection" so that it doesn't flash the "no results found" message while the app is initially loading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to meteor! If this was a production app, my first comment would be that you shouldn't use autopublish - and especially not with 1k records. The right way to do this is with a more complex pagination framework. That aside, we can make your current UI much faster with a few tweaks:

1. You can use mongo's [regexp](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator, which appears to be much faster than using `where`. That by itself is a big win.
2. `isMatch` calls `codes` which is a pretty big performance hit since it reruns an already expensive query twice. Instead we can replace this call with a session variable.
3. It seems a little silly to list all 1k codes right off the bat. I limited it to 100 in my code, but again in a production app I'd use pagination.
4. I reduced the necessary query length to just `> 1` which still seems fast. But you should tune to taste.

Here are my changes:

```js
Template.results.codes = function () {
  var query = Session.get('query');
  var cursor = query && query.length > 1 ? Codes.find({code: new RegExp(query)}) : Codes.find({}, {limit: 100});
  Session.set('isMatch', cursor.count() > 0);
  return cursor;
};

Template.results.isMatch = function() {
  return Session.get('isMatch');
};
```

---

Here's a quick example of how to make this work after running `meteor remove autopublish`.

Add a subscription to your client:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('codes', Session.get('query'));
});
```

Add a publish to your server:

```js
Meteor.publish('codes', function(query) {
  if (query && query.length > 1) {
    return Codes.find({code: new RegExp(query)});
  } else {
    return Codes.find({}, {limit: 100});
  }
});
```

You can then remove the `limit` from the `Template.results.codes` function. In the publish, I think you'd need to tune the use of `limits` and `query.length` in a smart way, but this should get you started. I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little iffy about creating RegEx's from user-generated input, but I think I can handle sanitizing the input first.

Comment: Agreed. In a production app I'd remove the `insecure` package, and add `audit-argument-checks`. Then in the publish function I'd add a check that query be an alphanumeric string or something more restrictive.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important things you can do is optimize the collection you are publishing for your filter-as-you-type search. Using autopublish is not an option here.

[Here](http://dictionary.meteor.com/) is an example implementation using a dictionary with over 80,000 words. [Here's the source.](http://github.com/austinrivas/dictionary)

For the 'loading' effect I would use Iron-Router's `waitOn` method, link will also be in the comments

Comment: In order to achieve the "loading" effect I would use Iron-Router's `waitOn` method (https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#waiting-on-subscriptions-wait)

Comment: Is there any server-side code there? I just see a single file with 3 lines of comments in the server/ directory. Also, where does `Dictionary` get defined?

Comment: Edited so that both links fit in the answer.

Comment: @NathanFriedly the dictionary collection is defined in a seperate meteorite package [dataset-dictionary](https://github.com/awatson1978/dataset-dictionary)

awatson1978 is definitely someone worth following if you are interested in meteor and using big data

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the "regexp" operator is a good way to go.  Just make sure you handle the "special characters" appropriately.  For example, to you want to allow your users to pass a wildcard character like '*' (star) to mongo without verification, or should you treat it like a literal?

Answer (score 0):

I've created an [autocomplete package](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete) for this very purpose, which supports filtering of both client and server-side collections. It's built around Meteor's collections and reactivity, instead of the array-based approaches used in things like typeahead.

It uses most of the suggestions in this thread, and it's fairly fast on the client even for collections of 1000 records, and can use an index on the server to be even faster for large collections.